# Zero divisors are Nilpotent

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

For $p,n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $p$ is a prime then prove that every zero-divisor in $\mathbb{Z}_{p^n}$ is nilpotent.

Comment: What are your thoughts? Can you describe the zero-divisors?

Comment: If x and y are non zero element of give ring say R then xy=0 implies x=0 or y=0

Comment: That is the definition of the ring being an integral domain, which the ring in question is not.

Comment: Right. An element x is said to a left zero divisor if there is  non zero y such that xy=0

Comment: How to proceed please give me hint

Comment: Ok, now describe what that means in the given ring.

Comment: What do you mean ? Please repeat your question

Comment: What does it mean for an element to be a zero-divisor in the ring in question (i.e. the integers mod $p^n$).

Comment: Mean if x.y= multiple of p^n then it becomes zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a$ be a zero divisor in $\mathbb Z_{p^n}$ then it has to divisible by $p$. (You can show by that the contrary cant be zero divisor).

Then $a=pm$ for some $m$ in $\mathbb Z_{p^n}$ and what is $a^n=(pm)^n$ in $\mathbb Z_{p^n}$?